# Can you build a query in prisma without executing it?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

I have a find method in my api that takes these parameters

-limit  (optional)

-select (optional)

-sort   (optional)

-skip  (optional)

In MongoDB you can build a query like this :

```js
let query = model.find(query);

if(limit) {
  query.limit(limit)
 }
 
 if(skip) {
  query.skip(skip)
 }
 
// ....

let result = await query.exec();
```

Is there a similar option in Prisma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not Prisma user, but seems like you can build config parameters beforehand like

```js
let query = {
    skip: skip,
    take: limit
};
prisma.model.findMany(query)
```